# Use result from ParseQuery in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Want to understand how to use / take result from ParseQuery into a String[] not inside the query.

Here is the code:

```
public class OptionDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    String[] listitems = {here is where i want the result from the query};

    ListView mylist;
    TextView chosenProperty;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_dialog_content, null, false);
        mylist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ParseQuery<PropertyTypes> pt = new ParseQuery<PropertyTypes>(PropertyTypes.class);
        pt.whereExists("propertyType");
        pt.orderByAscending("propertyType");
        pt.findInBackground(new FindCallback<PropertyTypes>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<PropertyTypes> pList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < pList.size(); i++){
                        // Want to take the result from here and put it in the String array above
                        // String array "listitems"
                    }
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listitems);
        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
        mylist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There would be a direct method to do it if your List was of String, However, in your case it will depend on what the PropertyType class contains. Here's an example of what the code may looks like:

```
     listItems = new String[pList.size()];  

       for(int i = 0; i < pList.size(); i++){
               listItems[i]=pList.get(i).getStringObject();
            }
```

So pList.get(i) will get you your PropertyTypes class object, you should **replace getStringObject()** with a getter method within PropertyTypes that return a String

Above when you declare your member variable listItems, don't initialize it

```
String[] listItems;
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks a lot for the answer! I tried it but it gives me 'listitems' in red, says it doesnt recognize it. For sure i am doing smtg wrong, just dont really understand what... I am not a very experienced prog, as u can see :)), so can u help a bit more with that? I did it exactly as u wrote it. And one more things - yes - PropertyTypes holds strings!

Comment: All seems like like its suppose to work, no "red" fields there :) and when i press to open the dialog, the app is crashing... By the way, just to make it clear, when just entering string values to the array, meaning with out trying to get the data from parse.com, it works ok. So... Still fighting it )) it gives me the error on the Array adapter...

Comment: So, for what I understand, you want to pass your List results to the adapter?  If so, you will have to notifyDatasetChange() on the adapter once you put the value on the list.  excuse the lateness

Comment: Hi again. Ok - Got it. Will try to go with that and see how goes. Will keep u posted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. chose a JSON lib used to parse response from ParseDB. ( std JSON or Jackson are both good libs )

   {"results":[{"ACL":{"_User.objectId"
2. Change existing 'for' iteration inside of 'done()' to handle the JSON ARRAY that is a child of 'results' you see above

> ```
> ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) root.path("results");
>  int i = 0;
>  for (JsonNode node : array) {
>   i++;
> ```

3. Foreach element of the array get the string value of the columns that you want from 'PropertyTypes'

> YourCollection
>   myCollection.add(node.path("PTyp.property1").getTextValue());

finally...

> myCollection.toArray()

above uses 'jackson' lib for Json parse

gradle depencies

> compile files('libs/jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.2.jar')
>       compile files('libs/jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.2.jar')

Comment: Hi there! Thanks a lot for the answer! Will try and see how it goes!!

Comment: My sample assumesrest api which youare not using.

Comment: Yes i understood it... Want to stick with parse because its easier for me now.. Any ideas with using the parse query?

Comment: http://michaelevans.org/blog/2013/08/14/tutorial-building-an-android-to-do-list-app-using-parse/   see  'parsequery.getquery() '  in the link. its example of android SDK rather than REST api ...

Comment: Ok - will see it there and try to implement it. Will tell u how it went... Thanks a lot!